# How can I find out what color scheme is used by Google App

Tags: color

I'm from programmer background.

I would like to mimic the color scheme used in most Google Android app such as GMail, Google Analytic, to use them in my own app.

[image]

[image]

Those color looks

- Elegant
- Harmony
- Comfortable

I was wondering, usually, for a designer, how does they generate such color scheme?

Comment: Hi Cheok. I think [this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/how-can-i-improve-my-color-selection-skill) will help you. There a few similar ones, I recommend yo check the [color](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color) tag :)

Answer (score -1):

I usually go for pastel colors.  Especially with the new "flat craze."
For me I find a color I want; red, blue, orange, then null it down and make it look faded.  Or I brighten it up.  Depends really.  Everyone does things differently.